# Azure Table Storage Rowkey Query not returning correct entities

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

I have an azure table storage with a lot of entities and when I query for entities with Rowkey(which is of the data type "Double") less than 8888 by using the query "RowKey le '8888' ".I get also those entities with Rowkey greater than 8888 also.

[image: storage query]

Answer (score 6):

Even if you are storing a `Double` data type in RowKey, it gets stored as a `String` (both `PartitionKey` and `RowKey` are string data type). Thus the behavior you are seeing is correct because in string comparison `21086` is smaller than `8888`.

What you need to do is make both of these strings of equal length by pre-padding them with `0` (so your RowKey values will be `000021086` and `000008888` for example) and then when you perform your query, these values will not be returned.

Comment: I am using time ticks todo this operation. sometime it works fine and sometime not working. query is like this (PartitionKey ge '636022368000000000') and (PartitionKey le '063602279999999999')